# How to find font and string metrics in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, string, graphics, .net-core, system.drawing

I need to measure a string width and height in pixels in .NET Core 2.

In .NET Framework can be done using `Graphics.MeasureString` method, but in .NET Core, Graphics class no longer exists.

I also tried to find a Font or FontFamily class and extract the font size, font ascent and fond descent, but I couldn't find any or something similar.

With the current .NET Core version, that is still under hard work, it is possible to measure a string or to get the font metrics?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update** 17 November 2017

[**Windows Compatibility Pack for .NET Core is in preview as of today includes System.Drawing.Common and soon will include System.Drawing package.**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/16/announcing-the-windows-compatibility-pack-for-net-core/)

It is possible to use `CoreCompat.System.Drawing.v2` NuGet package which provides cross platform implementation of System.Drawing assembly based on Mono. I am using it currently on Windows, Linux and macOS in CI runs and so far without major hiccups.

DotNet team has finished already work on porting System.Drawing functionality to .NET Core (see issue #20325 in CoreFX GitHub repo [Support Full System.Drawing Functionality on .NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/20325) and issue #24909 [Ship .NET Framework compatibility pack](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24909). First preview release is planned for November 2017.

Shipping is planned with .NET Core 2.1.0 version and jointly with .NET Framework Microsoft compatibility pack. Package will support all major platforms with exception of UWP on Windows.

`Graphics.MeasureString` function is implemented [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/950f8f9e1180c03c729521d61cceead375d5cb1a/src/System.Drawing.Common/src/System/Drawing/Graphics.Windows.cs#L1958)

Comment: I saw that System.Drawing is in progress, but I didn't know that the next release will be this month. I will wait for 2.1. Thank you @Jacek.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Everything works well with the compatibility pack. Do you know when System.Drawing will be available in .NET Core and it will be os independent?

Comment: @alexpulver It will ship as RTW together with Core v2.1 what should happen in 2018 2Q

Answer (score 2):

I'm the maintainer of CoreCompat.System.Drawing. If you're on .NET Core 2.0, I'd recommend you switch to System.Drawing.Common instead. Although not released, there's already a preview version up on NuGet, which should be a drop-in replacement for CoreCompat.System.Drawing.

Comment: Why do you prefer it over CoreCompat.System.Drawing? Installed the latest preview from nuget - and the object catalog was empty.

Comment: System.Drawing.Common is the cross-platform version of System.Drawing being maintained by Microsoft. On Windows, it uses the same code as the .NET version of System.Drawing. On macOS and Linux, it uses most of the .NET System.Drawing code and parts of Mono's System.Drawing. In short, System.Drawing.Common is more compatible and better maintained. If you have issues with System.Drawing.Common, search for an issue (or open a new one) at https://github.com/dotnet/corefx.